# addOnTabSelectedListener not working inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I use tab layout inside a fragment and I want to use tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener to load fragments inside fragment but It does'nt work at all.Is there any suggestion to make this work or any new approach to have tabs inside fragment for loading new fragments?
thanks for your helps

here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        final SearchBookFragment searchbook=new SearchBookFragment();
        final SearchPeopleFragment searchpeople=new SearchPeopleFragment();

        TabLayout searchTabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.searchTabLayout);

        searchTabLayout.addTab(searchTabLayout.newTab().setText("book"));
        searchTabLayout.addTab(searchTabLayout.newTab().setText("person"));




        searchTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"selecteeeed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                switch(tab.getPosition()){

                    case 0:

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"boooook",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case 1:

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"peoppllllle",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Please describe the problem.

Comment: Your `return` statement is returning a newly inflated `View` that is not the one you inflated and setup above. Change it to `return view;`.

Comment: I edited the code but it's irrelevant to the problem

Comment: No, it is completely relevant to the problem. You just have other problems, too. Where is `searchFrameLayout`? Why aren't you using `getChildFragmentManager()` to transact those `Fragment`s? Is there something covering your tabs? Is there any visual feedback when you click them?

Comment: I changed the code to describe my problem and make it simple .I want to make a toast when each tab selected.but the method does'nt work.

Comment: now I get the point,thanks for mentioning the problem